# lists and arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, vba, sortedlist

I am extremely new at writing in VB.NET, and I did not even realise that there was a significant difference between VB.NET and VBA. I have been writing my application in Visual Studio, but I realised that I will need to port it over to VBA in Outlook, and there are some syntax issues that I need to deal with. I have already searched, but I cannot find any sort of definitive reference (like the msdn) for VBA or even VB6, which from what I hear is much closer to VBA than VB.NET.

I will include the relevant sections of code here. If anyone needs more context, please let me know--I can post the whole thing, it's not that long. I would like to keep this post as simple as possible, though.

```
Dim DateToday As String = String.Format("0:{yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now)
Dim Computers As New SortedList()
Dim disabledList As New List(Of String)
'\\ four additional lists
Dim compArray As Array

...

Computers.Add(ComputerName, ErrorState)
```

The new lists and sorted list give Expected: End of Statement at the parenthesis after List. The array gives Expected: identifier at Array. The string DateToday gives an expected end of statement at the equals sign. The attempt to add to the sorted list gives an Expected: =.

I have been working with VB.NET for maybe two or three days, and I have never worked with VBA or VB6 before, so I just do not have the experience required to know where to go from here. If any of you would be willing to help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: To put it simply, the code that you are writing is not valid VBA syntax.  VBA is a different language, and it doesn't support the .NET framework.

Comment: If you are looking for references, MSDN does indeed have comprehensive documentation for VBA :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278934%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: You could start with the VBA language reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Does your list really need sorting? Moreover you could use VB.Net with outlook using some COM addins; this is quite simple to develop but to update it you need Visual Studio, so it's a little trickier to deploy and update than VBA but you get the full power of .Net. Have a look at my blog, I've written an article to show how you can simply do that for Excel but it should equally apply to Outlook: http://pragmateek.com/extend-your-vba-code-with-c-vb-net-or-ccli/

Comment: Unfortunately I do need it to be sorted, as I will be comparing it to another list. I will take a look at the link you provided... thanks!

Comment: You can use the Outlook Object Module from VB.Net if that would work for you.

Comment: Yeah, if I just compile my vb.net project into an exe and run that, will it be able to interact with outlook? I thought that the only way to do that was to run a macro from within outlook

Comment: You do not need to sort things to compare them. Please tell us [what problem you are trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), not just how you have decided to solve it.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get a program to access outlook, check the subject and body of messages sent on a particular date (one of which contains a computer name), and then compare the computer names gathers via the emails to a list of prepared computer names. I am looking to see if any of them are missing. I don't care whether I do this with VBA or VB.NET, I just need to find a way to make it work. I hope this clears it up a bit!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will have to change some of your data types but the basics of what you just posted could be converted to something similar to this given the data types I used may not be accurate.

```
Dim DateToday As String: DateToday = Format(Date, "yyyy/MM/dd")
Dim Computers As New Collection
Dim disabledList As New Collection
Dim compArray(1 To 1) As String

'Assign data to first item in array
compArray(1) = "asdf"

'Format = Item, Key
Computers.Add "ErrorState", "Computer Name"

'Prints "ErrorState"
Debug.Print Computers("Computer Name")
```

Collections cannot be sorted so if you need to sort data you will probably want to use an array.

Here is a link to the outlook developer reference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866465%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Another great site to help you get started is 
http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx

Moving everything over to VBA from VB.Net is not going to be simple since not all the data types are the same and you do not have the .Net framework. If you get stuck just post the code you're stuck converting and you will surely get some help!

Edit:

```
Sub ArrayExample()
    Dim subject As String
    Dim TestArray() As String
    Dim counter As Long

    subject = "Example"
    counter = Len(subject)

    ReDim TestArray(1 To counter) As String

    For counter = 1 To Len(subject)
        TestArray(counter) = Right(Left(subject, counter), 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason I was using lists instead of arrays was that the program does not know for certain how many entries there will be in the array before it is done. But I can convert it to an array. A stupid question: do I have to declare the array at the beginning of the program, or can I wait until I determine how many spaces it will need, and then declare it?

Comment: You will have to loop through the data to determine the number of items that will be added to the array and store the number in a variable. Use ReDim to reinitialize the array to the correct size or depending on the format of your data you may be able to use ReDim preserve to prevent looping through your data twice, once to count, once to read. The only problem is that if you are using a multidimensional array you can only resize the last dimension. I'll put an example in my answer for you.