# How do I add elements to a list of arrays? This is for vba

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I declared the list of arrays as: Public BikeList As New List(Of String())

I need to add elements to this list ("Harley" , "American")
                                    ("Suzuki" , "Japanese")
                                    ("Scuzi" , "Italian")

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028592/lists-and-arrays-in-vba

Comment: Are you talking about adding items to an existing list of initialising a list when and where you create it? If the former, there's no difference at all between this and any other list. If you mean the latter, there's no difference at all between this and any other list. If you know how to add items to a list, you know how to add items to this list. If you don't know how to add items to a list, that's what you need to research. Not surprisingly, there will be instructions and examples all over the web.

Comment: Your title says "this is for VBA", but VBA doesn't have generic Lists such as `List(Of String)`. I suspect you are using VB.Net which is the VB language provided in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim BikeList As New List(Of String())
BikeList.Add({"Harley", "American"})
BikeList.Add({"Suzuki", "Japanese"})
BikeList.Add({"Scuzi", "Italian"})
```

I think I would actually prefer a two dimensional array.

```
Dim BikeArray As String(,) = {{"Harley", "American"}, {"Suzuki", "Japanese"}, {"Scuzi", "Italian"}}
```